# Change Customize Format in Control Panel by C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know my question is quite strange but maybe I can found a solution here.
I usually want to change some things in Customize Format but I have to go to so many steps:

1. Click the Start button, and then click Control Panel.
2. Click Clock, Language, and Region, and then click Regional and Language Options.
3. On the Formats tab, click Additional settings...
4. Change my settings, click OK.
   [image]

Is there any way to do this just by one click? I have some knowledge to use Visual Studio to write an application.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You can specify the culture settings used by setting it via `Thread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentUICulture`. This can then differ from the system settings

Comment: If you want to change them at system level, you can change values of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` using C# or Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System Level**

If you want to change them at system level, you can change values of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` using C# or PowerShell.

*C# Example*

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International", 
    "sDecimal", ",");
```

*PowerShell Example*

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sDecimal -Value ","
```

**Thread Level**

If you want to change those values just for your current thread scope, you can set them this way:

```
var current = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(current.Name); 
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```